# Утворення родового відмінка у словосполученні "сади Версаля / ю"

Tags: іменники, морфологія

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D1%96_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F) знаходжу варіант із закінченням -а:

> Сади і парк **Версаля** знаходяться на частині території колишніх Королівських володінь у Версалі і є частиною палацово-паркового ансамблю **Версаля**.

На сайті ж [Мандруємо та готуємо з Любою](https://liubaproduction.blogspot.com/2016/01/blog-post_19.html) пише варіант -у:

> Сади **Версалю** та вечір біля Ейфелевої вежі.

Отож як правильно: Версалю чи Версаля?

Comment: перепрошую, а в словниках ви перевіряли? Ось тут, наприклад: http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Версаль** – ім., ч.р. ІІ відміна. У [Правописі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm) знаходимо особливості  відмінювання іменників ч.р. ІІ відміни:

> 2. Іменники чол. роду в родовому відмінку однини приймають закінчення -а (у твердій та мішаній групах), -я (у м’якій групі), коли вони означають:
>
> г) назви населених пунктів: Воронежа, Голосієва, Житомира, Києва, Лондона, Луцька, Миргорода, Новгорода, Парижа, Святошина, Тернополя, Харкова.
> Примітка. Але -у, -ю пишеться у складених назвах населених пунктів, другою частиною яких є іменник, що має звичайно в родовому відмінку закінчення -у: Давидового Броду, Зеленого Гаю, Красного Лиману, Кривого Рогу, Червоного Ставу, Широкого Яру тощо;
> ґ) інші географічні назви з наголосом у родовому відмінку на кінцевому складі, а також із суфіксами /84/ присвійності -ов-, -ев- (-єв-), -ин- (-їн-): Дінця, Дністра, Іртиша, Колгуєва, Орла, Остра, Пирятина, Псла, Пскова, Тетерева;
>
> 3. Закінчення -у (у твердій і мішаній групах), -ю (у м’якій групі) мають іменники чол. роду на приголосний, коли вони означають:
>
> ї) назви річок (крім зазначених у п. 1), озер, гір, островів, півостровів, країн, областей і т. ін.: Амуру, Бугу, Гангу, Дону, Дунаю, Єнісею, Нілу, Рейну, Сейму; Байкалу, Ельтону, Мічигану, Світязю, Чаду; Алтаю, Ельбрусу, Паміру, Уралу; Кіпру, Котліну, Криту, Родосу, Сахаліну; Каніну, Пелопоннесу; Алжиру, Афганістану, Казахстану, Єгипту, Іраку, Китаю; Донбасу, Ельзасу, Кавказу, Сибіру.

Отже, слово **Версаль** підходить під пункт 2. г.,тому  нормативно Р.В. – **ВерсалЯ**.
Але, наприклад, у статті ПРОБЛЕМИ МОРФОЛОГІЧНОЇ ПАРАДИГМАТИКИ ОЙКОНІМІВ
ІМЕННИКОВОГО ТИПУ В СУЧАСНІЙ УКРАЇНСЬКІЙ МОВІ Лілія ДАШИНСЬКА та у статті  [В. М.. Винницький  ПРО ДЕЯКІ НЕТОЧНОСТІ У ТРАКТУВАННІ МОВОЗНАВЧИХ ПОНЯТЬ У СУЧАСНИХ ПРАВОПИСАХ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ](https://movoznavstvo.org.ua/component/attachments/download/155.html):

> Мовознавці  діаспори  не  підтримують  формулювання  правил  щодо  вживання  флексії
> -а (-я) в  Р. в.  однини  всіх  іменників  чоловічого  роду  ІІ  відміни,  „що  означають  назви
> місцевостей”, опублікованих в четвертій редакції правопису. Тому А. Горняткевич пропонує
> таке формулювання:
> „1)  неслов’янські  топоніми  завжди  мають  флексію  -у / -ю:  Берлін,  -у;  Ванкувер,  -у;
> **Версаль,  -ю.**.

Однак, незважаючи на ці неоднозначні думки між мовознавцями, за чинним правописом правильно **ВерсалЯ.**